# WPF Custom Routed event question

Tags: wpf, event-bubbling, routed-events

How do you get two unrelated controls to raise the same custom event?  All examples I have seen so far have an event defined within a single control, should I be taking a different approach?

Eg. I'd like to raise a custom bubbling event from an OnFocus handler for a button and a textbox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off let me say your question doesn't make it clear that you don't want to use the existing [UIElement.GotFocusEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocusevent.aspx), but I'll assume you know about it and have your reasons for not using it.

You can always register a custom event on a static class, and raise it wherever you want. The [Keyboard class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard(VS.85).aspx) does with all of its events (e.g. [Keyboard.KeyDownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.keydownevent(VS.85).aspx)).

```
public static class RoutedEventUtility
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent MyCustomEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("MyCustomEvent", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(RoutedEventUtility));
}
```

You raise the event just like you would any other RoutedEvent.

```
RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs(RoutedEventUtility.MyCustomEvent);
RaiseEvent(args);
```

If you want another class to own the event as a public field then you will need to add an owner.

```
public class MyCustomControl : Control
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent MyCustomEvent = RoutedEventUtility.MyCustomEvent.AddOwner(typeof(MyCustomControl));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, yes correct assumption about UIElement.GotFocusEvent.